# 'createVideoSource(boolean)' in 'org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory' cannot be applied to '(org.webrtc.CameraVideoCapturer)'

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

with google webrtc I've been facing this issue and this is the code for creating a video source

```
private VideoTrack getVideoTrack() {
    this.capturer = createCapturer();
    return factory.createVideoTrack("video1", factory.createVideoSource(this.capturer));
}
```

but I'm getting an error

```
'createVideoSource(boolean)' in 'org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory' cannot be applied to '(org.webrtc.CameraVideoCapturer)'
```

> any idea on why its giving an error?

thanks.

Comment: This seems like a dependency version problem. Can you show us your build.gradle of the module?

Comment: in another function where its         PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(c).createInitializationOptions());
        factory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().createPeerConnectionFactory();

Comment: I've switched to an older version of webrtc but no luck as all the code is based on the new version even online i found examples but its still gives error, also gradle is 3.1.3 dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513'

Comment: https://github.com/meshenger-app/meshenger-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/d/d/meshenger/RTCCall.java

the code on github

Comment: Where exactly do you see the error? At runtime?

Comment: As far as my research goes, the signature `createVideoSource(boolean)` has never existed. So the error you are getting is indeed strange. Do you have a full stacktrace? Is capturer null?

Comment: Thank you @JensV I fixed it and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed after 10 hours,

the fix is changing the code to

```
private VideoTrack getVideoTrack() {
    this.capturer = createCapturer();
    assert this.capturer != null;
    return factory.createVideoTrack("video1", factory.createVideoSource(this.capturer.isScreencast()));
}
```

and then initializing

```
capturer = new CameraVideoCapturer()
```

that fixed it

Comment: what do you mean? the capturer was just used for a second, then it is thrown away, replaced with another one?